# Can a Home member handover music from their iPhone to a HomePod?

Tags: iphone, music, homepod

My wife and I are in a Home account. I am the primary account holder signed in to the HomePod.

I can transfer music from my iPhone to the HomePod and back without a problem.

However my wife can’t seem to transfer the music.  When she brings the iPhone next to the HomePod, nothing happens.

Is this use case supported?
What does she need to do?

Comment: Did you setup multiuser on your HomePod?

Comment: I did set it up.  However, my wife's iPhone had to be upgraded from 13.2 to 13.2.3 before it (kind of) worked (never knew a 0.0.2 update was essential!).  However, even though all the right switches are on, the music doesn't transfer.